# How can I figure out the type of the power supply DC connector from its datasheet?

Tags: power, socket

I'm planning to use [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ac-dc-adapters/2064930) power adapter which says its connector is 5.5 x 2.1 x 12mm DC jack.

I need to find its panel mount counterpart to install in an enclosure, but there are many types of DC sockets where some are female some are male.  I cannot conclude the exact type of the connector from the [datasheet of this adapter](https://docs.rs-online.com/3629/A700000008936140.pdf) so I cannot figure out a counterpart.

Would [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/dc-power-connectors/0487842) work as counterpart?

Which parameter(s) should I look at?

Comment: No, the power supply has a 2.1mm centre hole, and the counter part you linked has a 2.5 mm pin (right at the bottom of the page, specificartions). Look for one with a 2.1mm pin.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks for the feedback. I checked for 2.1mm but for sockets theres only 2mm ones. Like this https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/dc-power-connectors/8782628 There's no 2.1mm inner diameter socket for some reason.

Comment: I got it 2mm pin is fine for 2.1mm diameter

Comment: IME these connectors are already de-facto standardized; you just need the right one; if you find something labelled as 5.5/2.1 (or 2.1/5.5) barrel jack, it'll be the right one. Then you can choose one that's panel mount and whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to find a manufacturer/type number of a matching socket, as there are so many, is going to one of the larger component sellers like Mouser or DigiKey and do a search for "power connectors" yielding [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-connectors/435), for example. Check visually if the results contain what you are looking for.

Then filter on what you know (inside diameter, outside diameter, panel-mount, current, depth, etc.), to find what you need, like [so](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-connectors/435?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygFwE4FcCmAaEA9lANogAsYYcATBPhWABxwDsI%2BAzIxy6%2ByFx5wY-QTACs1EAF18AB1RQQAZQwBLAHYBzEAF98VSYhApIGHPiKRSjRgAYpskAqWr0mnfvBxxHY6fM8QhIQag4YFjt%2BajJqGDJosgoEJxdIFXVtPQMfBOgTNCwgq1IwGLs4KNTFdLcPPV1dIA), for example.

This should give you a list of type numbers to use for your shopping.

I'm not sure the links I included are persistent or session-bound, but you get the idea.